# No right border on rows that end in multirow?

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn, border

I have a table:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\color{white}}>{\columncolor[gray]{0}}l X | X | X | X |}
  \cline{1-2}
  Proposal Code           & \\
  \hline
  Short Description       & \multicolumn{4}{X}{} \\
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Spread} &   &   &   &   \\
  \cline{2-5}
                          &   &   &   &   \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

This creates a table with four rows:

- A short row with two small cells. This works fine.
- A long row with one small cell and one large cell.
- Two long rows with five small cells apiece, with the first cell being a multirow.

The first row works fine. The second row doesn't have a right border despite the second and fifth columns having borders elsewhere. What gives?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues with your code:

- The four narrow columns are really of type `X|`, not `X`; note that each of these columns is associated with a vertical rule to the right. This explains why

  ```
  \multicolumn{4}{X}{}
  ```

  fails to draw a vertical line at its right-hand edge. What's needed is
- However, this still isn't quite right, as any text in this "wide" column will occupy only the width of the first of the four columns. What's really needed, then, is

  ```
  \multicolumn{4}{>{\hsize=4\hsize}X|}{}
  ```

  That way, if and when you start providing text material for the combined cell, it'll occupy all four of the underlying narrow columns.

There's a further, relatively minor point: Instead of placing

```
\multirow{2}{*}{Spread}
```

in the third row, you should place

```
\multirow{-2}{*}{Spread}
```

in the fourth row.

I'd also replace `>{\color{white}}>{\columncolor[gray]{0}}` with `>{\color{white}\columncolor[gray]{0}}`.

The result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent % <-- important
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | >{\color{white}\columncolor[gray]{0}}l *{4}{X|} }
  \cline{1-2}
  Proposal Code            & \\
  \hline
  Short Description        & \multicolumn{4}{>{\hsize=4\hsize}X|}{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla} \\
  \hline
                           &   &   &   &   \\
  \hline
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Spread} &   &   &   &   \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: All of these suggestions worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @asdfsdfwewrwe - You're most welcome.